# What does the word interference "fringe" mean?

Tags: interference

In the double slit experiment, if we are asked to find the number of interference fringes, does that mean we are asked for the number of maxima? Or the number of minima?

What is the definition of the word "fringe"?

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/interference-fringe It can be either. Refer to the question-setter for clarification of his/her meaning.

Comment: Fringe means on or at the edge, or it means bands of material at the edge of a dress for example.  The diffraction pattern resembles a bunch of edges or bands etc.

Comment: @PhysicsDave The everyday-usage definition of the term is irrelevant (and actively confusing) here.

Comment: Yes I got off topic, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal usage, it refers to the maxima of the interference pattern. More technically, it's probably more accurate to assign it to a *period* of the oscillation (so, from a maximum, through a minimum, and up to the next maximum, but also vice versa), but in regular usage the most common case is to use it as counting bright fringes.

Answer (score -2):

First an interference fringe is a dark or bright band caused by beams of light that are in or out of phase with each other. Now the bright parts are the constructive interferences.

The separation of the maxima is

```
d f = λ/ ( sin ⁡ θ)
```

and df is known as the fringe spacing. The fringe spacing increases with increase in wavelength, and with decreasing angle θ.

The fringes are observed wherever the two waves overlap and the fringe spacing is uniform throughout.

Now fringes are not always bands that are long in shape, they can be any shape:

[image]